# How to deal with parent.frames issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Ok, i have a frustrating problem with this. I have sense that solution is very simple, but i can not find it. I have a web page with frames scheme like this:

```
    <frameset rows="48px,*">
      <frame name="title" src="titol.aspx" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" />
        <frameset id="workFrame" cols="200,0,*,0">
          <frame name="menu" src="legend.aspx" frameborder="1" scrolling="yes" style="border:2px solid #FFF"/>
          <frame name="map" src="map.aspx" frameborder="1" scrolling="yes" style="border:2px solid #FFF"/>
          <frame name="loading" src="loading.aspx" frameborder="1" scrolling="yes" style="border:2px solid #FFF"/>
          <frame name="form" src="blank.aspx" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"/>

            </frameset>
         <noframes>
           <p>
               some text
           </p>
         </noframes>
   </frameset>
```

Now, i have a image in "title" frame which i codded that when it is clicked, it opens up a new window (pop up, not in new tab). In that window, i have several map examples (map names with links). How must i code the links if i want for maps to be shown in the "map" frame after user clicks on the map link? I tried:

```
             onclick="parent.frames['map'].location… = 'map.aspx'
             onclick="windows.opener.location.href = 'map.aspx' .....
```

I have no idea how to resolve this. Once more, when link is clicked in a new window, the chosen map must be shown in a "map" frame, and it would be also great if you could show me the code for automatic closing that new window after the user has clicked on a map link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it be something like

```
window.opener.parent.frames['map'].location.href = "map.aspx";
```

As the window.opener is the title page, and its parent is the frameset?

Comment: Beautiful. It never occurred to me to chain all that together. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Must you use frames? Frames cause problems for search engines indexing pages, bookmarking and printing pages. A good solution to this would be to use ajax to load the maps into a targetted div. There's lots of technologies out there - JQuery ajax being popular and importantly free. Works well cross browser.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Appreciate this may not be the answer you are looking for - advocating radical page redesign rather than quick fix.

Comment: I know, but the thing is that i didn't started on this project from the beginning, i just got involved on it, and i can't start all over again now. I know it's dumb solution, but that is the situation, i can only try to work with what i got right now.